# Перенос данных mySQL

Tags: mysql

Только начал изучать SQL, возник такой вопрос, не смог найти (скорее всего не грамотно вводил в поиск).
Имеется: таблица1 и таблица2 с одинаковой структурой (id (PK), строка1, строка2). Мне необходимо перенести данные в таблица1 (строка1, строка2) из таблица2 (строка1, строка2) по совпадению id("таблица1 id" = "таблица2 id"). Заранее благодарен за совет.

Comment: *Мне необходимо перенести данные* - перенос как бы предполагает, что таблица-приёмник пуста. Но если так - какое может быть *по совпадению id("таблица1 id" = "таблица2 id")*?

Comment: @Akina переносились товары на другую версию cms, а вот эти 2 колонки были нестандартные и не перенеслись модулем, теперь 2 таблицы с одинаковыми id, но в новой пустые колонки, необходимо взять 2 колонки со старой и перенести из них данные в новую таблицу (id совпадают).

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Comment: @Denis мне бы следовало конечно не упрощать. У таблиц больше колонок и они по именам не совпадают, так же имеют запись ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
  ADD KEY `name` (`name`);
 вторая таблица ADD KEY name (name) не имеет. При такой команде возникает ошибка дубликатов

Comment: @Iprit Главное чтобы порядок и тип данных совпадал можно вставлять все столбцы кроме ключа

Comment: *У таблиц больше колонок и они по именам не совпадают* - ну так перечислите поля в секции INSERT и замените звезду на список полей в секции SELECT. А ключи Вас вообще не должны волновать - если, конечно, копируемые данные не вызовут нарушения условий целостности (что необходимо проверить, и при обнаружении устранить, до начала копирования).

Answer (score 1):

> переносились товары на другую версию cms, а вот эти 2 колонки были нестандартные и не перенеслись модулем, теперь 2 таблицы с одинаковыми id, но в новой пустые колонки, необходимо взять 2 колонки со старой и перенести из них данные в новую таблицу (id совпадают).

Это НЕ называется переносом. Это обновление данных.

```
UPDATE new_table n, old_table o
SET n.empty_field_1 = o.field_1, n.empty_field_2 = o.field_2
WHERE n.id = o.id
```